# Implementing Shaka Player with Fairplay with Azure DRM service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, azure-media-services, drm, shaka

I have initialise shaka player with all necessary DRM configuration of fairplay. But I am not unable to load audio. I was to able integrate widevine and able to play it. No error is been shown and need to know what is the issue. Can anyone help to debug the issue. We are using Azure DRM services to convert the assets and generating the url. I am able to play URL in azure media player but not able able to play in shaka - player

```
    shaka.polyfill.installAll();
    if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
      this.videoElement = this.videoElementRef?.nativeElement;
      this.videoContainerElement = this.videoContainerRef?.nativeElement;
      this.initPlayer();
    } else {
      console.error('Browser not supported!');
    }

 this.player = new shaka.Player(this.videoElement);
    console.log(this.player)
   
    // this.player.configure({
   //       drm: {
   //         servers: {
   //         //  'com.widevine.alpha': '',
   //           'com.apple.fps.1_0':''
   //         },
   //       },
   //    });


   this.player.getNetworkingEngine().registerRequestFilter( (type:any, request:any) => {
 
     console.log("registerRequestFilter called") 

         if (type == shaka.net.NetworkingEngine.RequestType.LICENSE) {
           request.headers['authorization'] = "";
           request.url = this.serverProcessSPCPath
           console.log("getting license")       
      }
    });   

    
    try {
     const req = await fetch('URL');
     this.hlsCertificate = await req.arrayBuffer();
     console.log(this.hlsCertificate)
   
   } catch (error) {
     console.log('ERROR', 'Load FairPlay Certificate Error: ' + error)
    
   }
   
   this.player.configure('drm.initDataTransform', (initData:any,content:any,third:any) => {
   
    //const processedData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, (new Uint16Array(d)) as ArrayBuffer) .substring(1);
    const processedData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,Array.from<number>(new Uint8Array(initData.buffer))) ;
    const contentId = new URL(processedData.substring(1)).hostname;
    const cert = this.player.drmInfo().serverCertificate;
    this.serverProcessSPCPath = processedData.substring(1).replace('skd://', 'https://');
    return shaka.util.FairPlayUtils.initDataTransform(initData, contentId, cert);
});

  

this.player.configure('drm.advanced.com\\.apple\\.fps\\.1_0.serverCertificate',  new Uint8Array(this.hlsCertificate));
   
   let videoUrl = "URL";
   console.log(this.videoElement?.duration)
   console.log(this.player.getConfiguration()) 

   this.player.addEventListener('error', this.ErrHandler.bind(this))
   
   this.player.load(videoUrl).then(() => {
    
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    console.log('ERROR', 'Load Manifest Error: ' + error)
  
  })
```

[image]

Comment: I do not have iPhone/Mac device for testing, but you can have a look here [media-services-3rdparty-player-samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-3rdparty-player-samples/tree/master/src/shaka)

Comment: We tried this but its not working

Comment: Are you using native iOS playback or MSE (HTML Media Source Extensions) for Fairplay?  On iOS, only native playback (AvPlayer) is supported with Fairplay - so none of their callbacks  will ever hit.  On Mac Safari browser, the HTML5 MSE will work depending on the configuration of the player and if it is set to default (if not configured).

I believe AMP player doesn’t support MSE on Mac Safari, so it always falls back to native playback - which uses the AvPlayer player framework in the operating system directly.